# Cannot access websites hosted in China

Tags: web

I know there is this Chinese National Firewall that prevent Chinese access to website hosted outside of China. But recently I encountered its opposite, I have a site hosted in China and it been run OK for well over a year.  Recently, the site can only be accessed within China, but not out of China, which I found strange. I went on to just-ping.com to ping my site worldwide - besides China, all packets lost for everywhere else.

People, What is going on??
[image]

Comment: It seems likely that the only people who can answer this are the Chinese authorities.

Comment: How are you getting ping information back from your China site?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does not surprise me. What sites you can access or not in China even changes from city to city (Bejing <-> Shanghai) and from connection type (private DSL <-> hotel). And it changes by day...

Which means, even connections inside China are blocked between different parts of the country. Whatever this firewall really is, it is not only around China, but also between different regions(???) within in China.

I suggest to host your site on two places: Once inside China and once outside e. g. Taiwan.

Answer (score 0):

We need so much more info than this, without knowing if you have shared,VPS, or dedicated, the host. I can only guess that non-Chinese IPs are getting blocked by the host or possibly some transit provider. About the only thing you can do is talk to your host.